# strtotime doesn't return value while it works with value as hardcoded string

Tags: php, strtotime, import-from-excel

I am reading some data from excel and import them to the db. But having a strange problem. Everything is ok except the date section. the code section is:

```
$dob = $cells[$i][6];
echo $dob.'<br>';
$timestamp = strtotime($dob);
echo 'time- '.$timestamp;
echo 'time2- '.strtotime('01-01-2000');exit;
```

and the output is:

```
01-01-2000
time- time2- 946677600
```

The value  I used in the excel file is exactly the same 01-01-2000 as you can see from the output.

I don't understand why strtotime function can return a value for hardcoded string version but not with the variable read from excel file?

Thanks for any help.

**Solution:**
In case someone faces the same problem this is how I handled it.

```
$dob_temp = $cells[$i][6];
$dob_numbers = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$dob_temp);
$timestamp = strtotime(substr($dob_numbers,0,2).'-'.substr($dob_numbers,2,2).'-'.substr($dob_numbers,4,4));
$dob = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the string you retrieve from the excel file has some odd characters - for example a dash rather than a hyphen which trips up `strtotime`.

Example:

```
<?php
$dob = '01―01―2000';
echo $dob.'<br>';
$timestamp = strtotime($dob);
echo 'time- '.$timestamp;
echo 'time2- '.strtotime('01-01-2000');exit;
```

http://codepad.org/zKIqeHhO

You may want to clean up dates coming from the file or use something like [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to pass a format which matches the contents of the string.

Comment: I have tried DateTime::createFromFormat but didnt worked as well but I will try to clean or divide into substrings

Comment: thnx for the help. It was definitely a character problem. I even couldn't get substr successfully so I had to clean everything but numbers.